# How quickly could adrenaline booster drugs work?

Tags: science-based, medicine, trans-humanism

Here I'm thinking about something loosely similar to what Clarissa Mao has in The Expanse, in which she is able to have limited superstrength and agility for a short period before she passes out.

Instead of relying on implants that affect the entire endrocrine system as in the example here, would it be possible to have a similar effect via semi-conventional drug instead? How quickly could this take effect if it were given via either oral medication or an EpiPen style shot?

Comment: Would a Inhaler type of delivery be viable?

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhaler

Comment: Son, use good old nanotech - long lasting result is guaranteed, u'll beat that mao in no time, a squad if such maos

Comment: Adrenaline isn't on the list of [Drugs used in Warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_drugs_in_warfare). But this is and it sounds wonderful: "5 mg of Cocaine, 3 mg of Methamphetamine and 5 mg of Oxycodone in a compound they named D-IX". No drug can make you do anything you can't already do, but if you were on that shit you'd be *willing* to do anything, especially if it involved getting more.

Answer (score 14):

**This response is not medical advice. If you have questions, do a first aid course. Heck, do a first aid course anyway**

This summer I was working in remote areas alone - and there was significant chance of wasp stings. A single sting causes  anaphylactic shock in only a small percentage of the population, but the more stings, the more likely.
As a result, I was sent out with an epipen of adrenaline, and the instruction: 'if you get stung, use it'

Adrenaline is pretty safe. Buying an epipen is a ~\$150 where I live and contains 0.3mg adrenaline (1/2 a standard dose IIRC) with a shelf life of one year. You can do it over the counter without prescription. If you do a single-day training course on how to use a syringe/ampule, that cost goes down to the <\$10 range per full dose. Within that organization all the permanent staff have that training.

An epipen takes a few seconds to complete it's injection. Jab it into a persons thigh (or other muscle area) and *keep it in there* for 30 seconds to ensure the adrenaline actually gets into the patient. Make sure you point the right end at the patient. It's written on the device, so take the few seconds to read it - it's better that than injecting yourself in the thumb.

Adrenaline is fast acting and short-duration. It's been a while since my first aid training, but I'm pretty sure the body responds in seconds. It does all the things you expect it to naturally do when you feel adrenaline: your heart beats faster, your muscles react 'harder' and it amps your senses up a bit. But it isn't long term. Your body flushes it out pretty quick - think 10 mins sort of duration. The purpose of injecting yourself with an epipen to combat wasp stings is to keep you concious long enough to get away from the wasp nest, to trigger your PLB, and hopefully keep you alive until rescue. If there was enough toxins in those stings to stop your heart, they'll still stop your heart - just a bit later.
This means that if you're with a person who's been showing signs of going into shock/seizures/whatever and you've already given them adrenaline more than a few minutes ago - inject them again. I believe that sometimes there is still some adrenaline in an epipen after use, so if you have no other source of adrenaline, hit them with the same injector.

There's just one issue: I don't think adrenaline makes you superhuman. Last time someone gave you a scare did you turn into superman? Probably not. But it probably spiked your senses. If you aren't expecting your hero to suddenly turn into the hulk, but to just gain a 5% reflexes advantage over his opponent, maybe it would work.

[Techincally adrenaline is safe enough that a dose injected into a healthy person has very low risk of negative affects. So if you're really motivated, you could go down to a pharmacy, buy some and try it. That said, they guy on the other side of the counter will certainly want a better reason than "research for a fictional story I'm writing". If you do, please write about the experience!]

If I have any mistakes about the use/effects of adrenaline, I'm keen to know, so please edit this answer or comment below.

Comment: Hey man, what a job it was, really curious, was quite surprised, never heard of such stuff - terraforming jungles on venus or what? Lol))

Comment: Conservation field work in New Zealand: putting out/servicing trail cameras, dataloggers and audio recorders scattered through the forest, performing transects to monitor birds, wilding pine control etc. etc.

Comment: Good stuff. I think I have seen a youtube channel of a guy from those places(not sure, do not remember) who was figthing wasps, makes all sorts of contraptions and tests them in a hobby revenge way. Was thinking for some time on that problem as well, quite interesting problem, but never thougth it has such a touch to it. Thanks for information.

Comment: Regarding response time: The built-in adrenaline dump for a human takes effect in about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**Pretty darn quick**

Adrenaline itself is the drug, and is important in the fight-or-flight response by increasing blood flow to muscles, and flow output of the heart.

A fight/flight reaction that takes more than seconds to act would be utterly useless.

---

I once experienced a dream where I felt I was falling, and then in the dream impacted the ground (which is uncommon)  The body was "fooled" and must have released adrenaline because without moving, my heart rate increased dramatically and I woke right-up immediately.  It was unpleasant, there was no dozing-off after that wakeup.

Similar things have happened during impending accidents while cycling - once I lost traction on front wheel during a downhill turn and ended up rolling off a cliff.  Time literally slowed down as I was trying to brake and regain balance.
 If the adrenaline response was more than two seconds of real-time, I'd have been over the edge before the chemical reaction kicked in.

---

**Administration, Fast**

An oral tablet would be too slow to digest.  An injection in the arm would reach the brain and heart within 2-4 seconds, based on a blood-speed of ~5 km/h.  Some fancy kind of "sub-dermal" or slap injector that doesn't use a needle would be faster again, without having to find a blood vessel.  Or for your needs, a patient with a permanently installed Line would make the needle method reasonably quick.

The fastest way to get adrenaline into the blood would be to inhale a vapour.  Your lungs are basically a direct path to the blood stream, so as long as the alveoli in the lungs can pass the gaseous adrenaline-compound, it would hit like a sack of bricks (like going from sober to drunk on a lung-full of aerisolised alcohol.)

A similar solution might be a super-fine powder in the mouth, to be absorbed through the lining of the mouth, though keeping it dry and not blowing away might be challenging.   Perhaps a glass vial, somewhat like a one-time cyanide capsule of the cold-war spy might work here, though glass would be unpleasant as well.

Similarly, there are other parts of the Human body that are "thin" and provide relatively easy access to the bloodstream - which is exactly how STDs can transit between bodies more easily.  Probably not the most comfortable way to administer a drug in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

As been sayed, the inhalator would be pretty fast, if the people is in such condition that can powerfully inhale. I think the fastest way is IV'd on the vein going to brain. But that may cause some people distress, So second fastest would be the hit to the heart. If someone has overdosed or is in insuline coma. Had to do it once, hit it through chest to the heart. Situation was pretty bad, we were on a very little boat on a sea, and the waves got bigger and bigger. Suddenly, friend gets white and sweaty and drops on the floor, After full panic mode, found it in his stuff and we handled the boat to to the coast.. Phew.

Comment: Just a thought, but arteries go to the brain, veins from it (minor point). Welcome to the site Julia.

Comment: Yes. And that is why the heart is fastest way, if feels unconfortable to stab artery in neck. Of course, if you put it in any venous, it would take max ~2-3sec to hit brain.. That is why i dont get why the stabbing to the heart is in use .. Probably the victim won't die because of that second of waiting time :P Even from leg, it hits brain in few seconds intravenous.. But yes, in the small boat crushing everywhere, veins are not the easiest target :P And thank you, Antie-ant. :)